# Filter `List` based on another `List`

Tags: java, arrays, list, filter, java-stream

I am using the function below to filter a list based on another list. For example: programLines `[1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 13]` and lines `[9, 10, 13, 14]` into this output `[9, 13]`. However i want to change it to this output--> `[9,0,13,0]` in other words to fill-out rest elements with value `0`.

```
public List<Integer> filter(List<Integer> lines, List<Integer> programLines)              
            List<Integer> listOutput =
                lines.stream().filter(programLines::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return listOutput;
          }
```

Comment: If it helps, a text and video tutorial - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/streams.html. Map function is mentioned there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `filter`:

```
public List<Integer> filter(List<Integer> lines, List<Integer> programLines)              
    List<Integer> listOutput =
        lines.stream()
             .map(i -> programLines.contains(i) ? i : 0)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return listOutput;
}
```

If `programLines` is large, it may be useful to convert it to a `Set` for better performance:

```
public List<Integer> filter(List<Integer> lines, List<Integer> programLines)              
    Set<Integer> filter = new HashSet<>(programLines);
    List<Integer> listOutput =
        lines.stream()
             .map(i -> filter.contains(i) ? i : 0)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return listOutput;
}
```

Comment: i am getting this output `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 13]` but what i need is like this: `[9,0,13,0]`

Comment: @Alex it looks like you swapped the Lists. If you are streaming over the shorter list ([9, 10, 13, 14]) the output must have exactly 4 elements.

Comment: Do not assign result into a variable, return immediately instead.

Comment: @Eran - How fast and accurately you type! Amazing! Your answer was posted exactly after one minute when the question was posted.

Comment: @Eran how can i get the output that i want? could you please change the code accordingly

Comment: @Alex change the order of the arguments you passed to the `filter(List<Integer> lines, List<Integer> programLines)` method.

Comment: @Eran i accept your answer thanks, could you please change the code so that the first element of the result always has the value `1`?

Comment: @Alex I suggest you make that change after the stream pipeline (simply add `listOutput.set(0,1);` before the return statement).